# How I can peform scroll on Facebook in background with Selenium?

Tags: python, facebook, selenium-webdriver, scroll, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scroll down friend request list, but it doesn't work when my browser is in background. Actually I'm not sure that the issue is with scroll or with Facebook pagination nature. Page doesn't scroll in background or Facebook load more results only when page tab is currenctly active. I use it on Chrome. Chromedriver version: 120.0.6099.109

My code to scroll down looks like this:

```
def scroll_page(driver):
    i = 1
    while True:
        try:
            row = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"(//div[@data-visualcompletion='ignore-dynamic' and not(@role) and not(@class)])[{i}]")
            if row:
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({ 'behavior': 'smooth', 'block': 'center' });", row)
                i += 1
            else:
                break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error while scrolling: {str(e)}")
            break
    return i > 1
```

Is that effect I'm looking for is even doable? Thank you guys!